# c# wpf High quality image to byte and back

Tags: c#, wpf, image, sockets

So im transfering an image's source over a socket and in order to do that i have to convert it to byte[] form. I managed to that using this functions in order to convert the imagesource.

```
    public static BitmapSource ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(Byte[] imageData)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms,
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            return decoder.Frames[0];
        }
    }
    public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        var image = imageSource as BitmapSource;
        byte[] data;
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Now my problom is that after converting an image back it drops down in quality and all parts that were originally transparent turn black.

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: Use PNG. Don't use Jpeg. Jpeg is lossy (the quality drop you noticed) and doesn't support transparency. Side note: Don't say you want "*image to byte[]*" if you mean encoding an image in a certain format (like PNG, JPG, etc...). "*image to byte[]*" usually means wanting the uncompressed raw pixel data...

Comment: could you not just transfer the *file* instead? currently, this code is a transcoder.

Comment: When you search "image to byte[]" on StackOverflow, people usually mean both raw pixel data and encoding, so don't take that too serious. Besides that, use PngBitmapEncoder of course.